# name 'TextPath' is not defined

Tags: python, pandapower

I've tried running a program which imports the Pandapower library, and I get the Error:

```
NameError: name 'TextPath' is not defined
```

I installed Pandapower via pip install normally, and it works good, but it seems to have Problems with "`pandapower.plotting.collections`" and the class "`class CustomTextPath(TextPath):`"

Minimal Code:

```py
import pandapower as pp

import pandapower.plotting as plot
```

TracebacK:
`Traceback (most recent call last): File "-\Test.py", line 2, in <module> import pandapower.plotting as plot File "-\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandapower\plotting\__init__.py", line 1, in <module> from pandapower.plotting.collections import * File "-\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandapower\plotting\collections.py", line 36, in <module> class CustomTextPath(TextPath): NameError: name 'TextPath' is not defined`

Comment: Please show your code as a [mcve] and include the full traceback.

Comment: Is this error triggered _by the 2 imports and nothing more_? If not, that's not a [mcve].

Comment: Yes it is, I created a new file and only copied these two lines, and still get the error
I installed Pandapower via Cmd pip install, and no problems there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in `pandapower`.  They depend on having matplotlib installed.  The code catches its absence with a `try`/`except` but still tries to use the elements it would have imported.  So, do a `pip install matplotlib` and you should be good.

Comment: Thank you so much! Nailed it, works now as intended

Comment: [The Issue](https://github.com/e2nIEE/pandapower/issues/1212)